# Achieving CaseInsensitiveComparer functionality in winRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

winRT collection is not providing this. can anyone tell how can i achieve this functionality in winRT ?

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
        var string1 = "AbCdEfG";
        var string2 = "aBcDeFg";
        var a = string1.ToLower().CompareTo(string2.ToLower());
        var b = String.Compare(string1, string2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```